# Update all peers with value from the single peer having data in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table `customers` with multiple rows per name. I have the `SELECT` query reporting the right information, but I'm having trouble formulating the `UPDATE` statement.

How can I build an `UPDATE` statement to make all rows with the same name match on `address`, i.e. copy from the peer row with address data.

Here's my `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers b
WHERE (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM customers b
        WHERE a.name = b.name
        ) > 1
GROUP BY a.customerid
```

Example results:

```
Record 1 - John Smith / 123 Address ln
Record 2 - John Smith / <blank address>
Record 3 - John Smith / <blank address>
Record 4 - Tim Johnson / 456 Test Ave
Record 5 - Tim Johnson / <blank address>
```

Desired result:

```
Record 1 - John Smith / 123 Address ln
Record 2 - John Smith / 123 Address ln
Record 3 - John Smith / 123 Address ln
Record 4 - Tim Johnson / 456 Test Ave
Record 5 - Tim Johnson / 456 Test Ave
```

There are over 10,000 duplicated rows, so I'm having trouble writing sufficient constraints to build a 'catch-all' `UPDATE` statement to pick a 'parent' row as template for its 'child' rows. Every `UPDATE` statement I build seems to produce results like the following:

```
Record 1 - John Smith / 123 Address ln
Record 2 - John Smith / 123 Address ln
Record 3 - John Smith / 123 Address ln
Record 4 - Tim Johnson / 123 Address ln
Record 5 - Tim Johnson / 123 Address ln
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE customers a
SET    address = b.address
FROM   customers b
WHERE  a.name = b.name
AND    a.address IS NULL
AND    b.address IS NOT NULL;
```

Assuming:

- `<blank address>` is supposed to mean `NULL`
- There is at most *one* row with address per name.
- Names are actually unique identifiers - which they are not for real people names.

Else you have to be more specific.